# Android Video Streaming playing slowly?

Tags: android, video, video-streaming

I am developing a video based android application. I want to play a video (Video Format: mp4) from a URL. But it's not live stream video stored in the server. Get video URL from JSON object and playing video. The video is playing but not in a good manner.

Sometimes the audio is mismatched then take more time to play some take more time to buffer. But with the same video and same wifi speed I have on my system when playing with chrome it's playing well. I don't know what I am doing wrong? I also tried with android video view but the same problems occurred.

My code to start video player

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
 intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(uri), "video/*");
 startActivity(intent);
```

My code to playing with video view

```
VideoView vidView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.myVideo);
String vidAddress = "https://archive.org/download/ksnn_compilation_master_the_internet/ksnn_compilation_master_the_internet_512kb.mp4";
Uri vidUri = Uri.parse(vidAddress);
vidView.setVideoURI(vidUri);
MediaController vidControl = new MediaController(this);
vidControl.setAnchorView(vidView);
vidView.setMediaController(vidControl);
vidView.start();
```

Comment: are you testing on Emulator or real device?

Comment: i checked with real device and emulator

Answer (score 0):

What android version did you try? Because https is not supported before android 3.1.

Check supported protocols and media formats [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MediaPlayer to do this.

```
 mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
 mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
 Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
 headers.put("rtsp_transport", "tcp");
 headers.put("max_analyze_duration", "500");
 mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, Uri.parse(videoUrl), headers);
```

Comment: Please add some description to what the codes doing. :-)